# Back Stack in fragments not working

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment-backstack

I have a home activity in that I am replacing fragments as required.

In home activity I have main fragment, then from main fragment I am replacing a Transport fragment, from Transport fragment I am replacing TransportList Fragment.

Now as I press back from TransportList fragment I see the main fragment instead of Transport fragment.

I have added the fragments to backstack still its working like this.

Home activity

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    private boolean mBackPressCancelled = false;
    private static final long BACK_PRESS_DELAY = 10000;
    private long mBackPressTimestamp;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = HomeActivity.this.getFragmentManager();
        MainFragment fragment = new MainFragment();
        fragmentManager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mycontainer, fragment,"MAIN_FRAGMENT").commitAllowingStateLoss();

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        // Do nothing if the back button is disabled.
        if (!mBackPressCancelled) {

            // Pop fragment if the back stack is not empty.

            if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {

                mTxtTitle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mLogo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                super.onBackPressed();
            }
            else {
                if (snackbar != null) {
                    snackbar.dismiss();
                }
                long currentTimestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();

                if (currentTimestamp < mBackPressTimestamp + BACK_PRESS_DELAY) {
                    super.onBackPressed();
                } else {
                    mBackPressTimestamp = currentTimestamp;

                    Toast.makeText(this,"press again",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Transport fragment :

```
       mBtnSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            TransportListFragment fragment1 = new TransportListFragment();
            fragmentManager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mycontainer, fragment1).addToBackStack("G").commit();

        }
    });
```

Whats going wrong here please help.Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the following lines when you add new Fragment to the BackStack:

```
fragmentManager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
```